# Vim polluting my fs

Tags: windows-7, vim

I'm new to Windows, but Vim seems to be polluting my fs.

- every time I open a file with Vim, a `_viminfo` file is created in that files directory
- every time I edit a file, a `.swp` file is generated, but that `.swp` file persists even after saving/closing the original.

Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't intended behavior.  The _viminfo file should be in your user directory, and the .swp files should disappear after you unload the buffer or exit Vim.

Which installer did you use?  What version of Vim is it, including patchlevel? (`:version` while running Vim.)

Comment: Downloaded from http://www.vim.org/download.php, used the gvim73_46.exe installer. Version is 7.3 (patches 1-46)

Comment: That is very strange. Do you have any custom Vim configuration, other than what the installer created for you?

Comment: Pretty small _vimrc; syntax, lines, columns, numbering

Comment: Is Vim being killed somehow, without being allowed to properly shut down?

Comment: Sorry for being slow - "vacation". Nope, killing with `:wq`

Comment: Something is broken, but I don't have enough information to even guess at what the problem is. I'm reluctant to just recommend reinstalling Vim, but at this point it's all I can think of.

Comment: I did a clean install - same issue

Comment: What does `:echo $HOME` and `:echo $TMP` output?

Comment: `C:` and `C:\Users\me\Appdata\Local\Temp`

Comment: Okay, `$HOME` shouldn't be `C:`, it should be your user directory. Could it be that something external to Vim is misconfigured or otherwise messed up?